# Android build fails with kotlin-reflect and proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I am unable to build my release product if I include `kotlin-reflect` with it. I attempted adding this to proguard configuration:

```
-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
```

But it did not help at all. Here is the error result from the gradle build:

```
Optimizing...
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
   Class       = [kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/renderer/DescriptorRendererImpl]
   Method      = [renderPossiblyInnerType(Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;Lkotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/impl/descriptors/PossiblyInnerType;)V]
   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Stacks have different current sizes [0] and [1])
 Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stacks have different current sizes [0] and [1]
```

I am using kotlin 1.1.1 (and gradle 3.3, if that matters.)
j

Comment: You probably need to also keep the members and their names

Comment: use `-dontoptimize` in the proguard config

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar errors with kotlin reflect class and proguard, solved adding in the -optimizations

!class/unboxing/enum

My bug was related to this [Android Proguard failing with "Value 'i' is not a reference value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185060/android-proguard-failing-with-value-i-is-not-a-reference-value)
and found the fix in one of the comments